# Has dependence, but when compile hasn't

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, javassist

Has dependency: `org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile`

```
C:\Users\vydn\Desktop\boot>mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring Boot Web Application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ spring-boot-web ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.6/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.6.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.6/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.6.pom (5.4 kB at 3.8 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.6/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.6.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.6/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.6.jar (32 kB at 40 kB/s)
[INFO] guru.springframework:spring-boot-web:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.194:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.997 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-06T10:41:07+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/296M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\vydn\Desktop\boot>
```

This is error message:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-06-06 10:41:39.617  INFO 6020 --- [           main] g.s.SpringBootWebApplication             : Starting SpringBootWebApplication on Desktop137 with PID 6020 (C:\Users\vydn\Desktop\boot\target\classes started by vydn in C:\Users\vydn\Desktop\boot)
2017-06-06 10:41:39.619  INFO 6020 --- [           main] g.s.SpringBootWebApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-06 10:41:39.882  INFO 6020 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5a955565: startup date [Tue Jun 06 10:41:39 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-06 10:41:41.068  INFO 6020 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2017-06-06 10:41:41.077  INFO 6020 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-06-06 10:41:41.078  INFO 6020 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-06-06 10:41:41.169  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-06 10:41:41.169  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1290 ms
2017-06-06 10:41:41.311  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.312  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.312  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.312  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.313  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.313  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/console/*]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.314  INFO 6020 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.681  INFO 6020 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-06 10:41:41.696  INFO 6020 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-06-06 10:41:41.834  INFO 6020 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-06-06 10:41:41.836  INFO 6020 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-06 10:41:41.840  INFO 6020 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-06 10:41:41.876  INFO 6020 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-06 10:41:41.889  WARN 6020 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
2017-06-06 10:41:41.891  INFO 6020 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-06-06 10:41:41.896  WARN 6020 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2017-06-06 10:41:41.901 ERROR 6020 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at guru.springframework.SpringBootWebApplication.main(SpringBootWebApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:199) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I would use maven's shade plugin, and shade the dependency to my jarfile (if that's an option here, which it seems it is)

Comment: You true. You can answer the question.

Comment: Don't use the `maven-shade-plugin` you are using Spring Boot which already provides that functionality. Using the Shade plugin will not work with Spring Boot. Purge your local repository (you might have a borked jar) using `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` before building the artifact. This will force a redownload of all dependencies.

Comment: Or just go to .m2 folder find the dependency by hand and see if it is broken for sure (like 1kb). You can always delete the dependency manually and rebuild the project which will cost redownload. If the problem persists try old school downloading the jar from the internet or try changing the version in `pom.xml` .